# Error stating that bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle when using 'has_secure_password`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

But it is included in the Gemfile. When I `bundle install`, it says I am `using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)`

Commenting out the `has_secure_password` line from my only model stops this error from occurring.

I've Googled like mad and tried specifying different versions in the Gemfile to no avail.

Comment: What happens when you run `bundle exec rails server` instead of just `rails server`?

Comment: It works. And now the issue isn't happening when I run just `rails s`. Does that make sense?

Comment: What server are you running? Sounds like your development server can't find the gem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you resolved this or not, but I worked through this error last night. Shutting down and restarting the server worked for me.

(Ctrl+C)

rails server

Answer (score 0):

This may have been simply needing to restart the server.